# Como aumento o brilho de um elemento com Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Em minha página eu tenho diversos elementos com diferentes cores de fundo. Eu gostaria de saber como poderia fazer para ao clicar em um botão aumentar o brilho da cor, deixá-la mais clara.

É possível fazer isto utilizando [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) / [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)? Como?

Comment: Sei não, to achando que isso aqui devia mudar pra BrunoOverflow. Tá parecendo um blog seu.

Comment: _Apoiamos a re-escrita de perguntas ou respostas do Stack Overflow, desde que elas beneficiem a sua comunidade. Tenha sempre em mente, porém, que traduções automatizadas ou mal escritas não são permitidas._ http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com

Comment: Se tiver maiores dúvidas por favor utilize o meta.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Para fazer isto é necessário converter a cor para `HSV` para alterar o brilho.

**[Veja o exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8cMX/7/)**

### Convertendo para HSV (para alterar o brilho)

`HSV` significa `Hue` (tom), `Saturation` (saturação) e `Value` (valor). Conforme a imagem a seguir mostra

[image: hsv]

`v`, ou seja `Value`, corresponde ao brilho.

A função a seguir converte um valor `RGB` para `HSV`.

```
function RgbToHsv(r, g, b) {
    var min = Math.min(r, g, b),
        max = Math.max(r, g, b),
        delta = max - min,
        h, s, v = max;

    v = Math.floor(max / 255 * 100);
    if (max == 0) return { h: 0, s: 0, v: 0 };
    s = Math.floor(delta / max * 100);
    var deltadiv = delta == 0 ? 1 : delta;
    if( r == max ) h = (g - b) / deltadiv;
    else if(g == max) h = 2 + (b - r) / deltadiv;
    else h = 4 + (r - g) / deltadiv;
    h = Math.floor(h * 60);
    if( h < 0 ) h += 360;
    return { h: h, s: s, v: v }
}
```

Agora que tenho a cor em `HSV` eu posso alterar o valor de `V` para alterar o brilho.

O próximo passo é obter o valor em `RGB` para atualizar o estilo do elemento. A seguinte função converte de `HSV` para `RGB`

```
function HsvToRgb(h, s, v) {
    h = h / 360;
    s = s / 100;
    v = v / 100;

    if (s == 0)
    {
        var val = Math.round(v * 255);
        return {r:val,g:val,b:val};
    }
    hPos = h * 6;
    hPosBase = Math.floor(hPos);
    base1 = v * (1 - s);
    base2 = v * (1 - s * (hPos - hPosBase));
    base3 = v * (1 - s * (1 - (hPos - hPosBase)));
    if (hPosBase == 0) {red = v; green = base3; blue = base1}
    else if (hPosBase == 1) {red = base2; green = v; blue = base1}
    else if (hPosBase == 2) {red = base1; green = v; blue = base3}
    else if (hPosBase == 3) {red = base1; green = base2; blue = v}
    else if (hPosBase == 4) {red = base3; green = base1; blue = v}
    else {red = v; green = base1; blue = base2};

    red = Math.round(red * 255);
    green = Math.round(green * 255);
    blue = Math.round(blue * 255);
    return { r: red, g: green, b: blue };
}
```

---

Para exemplificar é possível utilizar o seguinte método:

```
function AppendColor(light) {
    $(".dark").each(function(i){
        // obtem a cor em RGB do elemento
        var color = $(this).css("background-color");
        color = color.replace(/[^0-9,]+/g, "");
        var red = color.split(",")[0];
        var gre = color.split(",")[1];
        var blu = color.split(",")[2];

        // converte rgb para hsv
        var hsv = RgbToHsv(red,gre,blu);

        // converte hsv para rgb modificando `v`
        var rgb = HsvToRgb(hsv.h, hsv.s, light);

        // cria uma nova div e seta a nova cor
        color = "rgb(" + rgb.r + "," + rgb.g + "," + rgb.b + ")";
        $("<div />")
            .css("background", color)
            .attr("title", color)
            .appendTo($(".light").parent());
        $("<span />").html(" ").appendTo($(".light").parent())
    });
    $("<br />").appendTo($(".light").parent())
}

// Valores para teste
AppendColor(25);
AppendColor(50);
AppendColor(75);
AppendColor(90);
AppendColor(95);
AppendColor(97);
AppendColor(99);
AppendColor(100);
```

Resultado:

[image: resultado]

Comment: A função `RgbToHsv` devia retornar um objeto ao invés de um array no caso `max == 0`, não?

Comment: Tem razão, corrigi. Obrigado!

Comment: interessante o código e muito bom!