# Acessibilidade (contraste) via Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, acessibilidade

Tenho um site que tenho que ter os seguintes métodos:

Aumentar fonte,
Diminuir fonte,
Contraste.

Já consegui os dois primeiros, preciso agora fazer o contraste com javascript puro.

Alguém já fez algo do gênero?

Preferencialmente sem uso do Jquery ou outro framework.
Um exemplo que vi foi no http://www4.serpro.gov.br/servicos/css/central-de-servicos-do-serpro/accessibility-info

Mas não consegui reproduzir apenas via javascript.
Valeu.

Comment: Isto aqui deve te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/691/como-aumento-o-brilho-de-um-elemento-com-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Apenas JavaScript" quer dizer sem mexer com CSS? A maneira mais simples parece ser definir o estilo alternativo em CSS e associá-lo à uma classe que pode ser dada ao corpo da página.

Por exemplo, acrescente esta regra à sua folha de estilos:

```
body.contraste {
    background: #000000;
}
```

E um botão que execute o código:

```
var
    className = 'contraste',
    el = document.querySelector('body');
if (el.classList) {
    el.classList.add(className);
}
else {
    el.className += ' ' + className;
}
```

Este é o inicio de uma forma de solucionar seu problema. O código em JavaScript não depende de framework o biblioteca alguma. Funciona nos navegadores atuais e no IE a partir do 8.

A lógica da solução é que existe um grupo de regras que estiliza a página no "modo contraste" (seja ele qual for) e estas regras valem enquanto o corpo da página (o elemento `body`) tem a classe contraste...

Comment: Pode ser usado sim CSS, no caso o que não posso utilizar é frameworks. Teria que ser com javascript puro, vou tentar essa sua solução.